# How to copy only the table structure?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create a database. It has up to 9 tables in future it may exceed. But the structure (number of columns and column name) of table is same for all tables. I know that there is an option to copy the structure of table and rename it and use it but I don't know how to do it exactly. Please give me the relevant answer so that it reduces my code.

Comment: your objective is not clear! you want to create new tables later with the same structure in the database? if yes, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Copy the table, then DELETE (not DROP) it all (without using a WHERE clause).

Comment: yes,i want to create new tables with same structure.the problem is that i don't know exactly how to get the structure of old table in android @ahmad

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the columns from the base table via `PRAGMA table_info (<yourtable>)`

e.g.

```
String sqlstr = " PRAGMA table_info (" + table_name + ")";
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery(sqlstr, null);
```

The resultant cusors has rows with columns :-

**cid** (rowid)

**name** (name of the column)

**type** (column type e.g. INTEGER)

**notnull** (0 if can be null)

**dflt_value** (default value if one)

**pk** (0 if not part of the primary key otherwise 1,2... if part of the primary key)

You could then build the SQL from this.

---

Another alternative could be to extract the **SQL** used to create the table via :-

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='<yourtable>'
```

You could then alter the resultant SQL, changing the base table name to the new table name.

---

A third option is to copy the table using something like

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT * FROM basetable WHERE 0
```

However, this isn't a full comprehensive copy of the structure, e.g. primary keys aren't created.